# Matrix in crystal report

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i badly need help.
i am new to crystal report and visual studio.

my prof give us an assignment and i cant get the output he wants to see.

right now i am using visual studio 2010 and crystal report
and it doesn't show the right output.

the data-table in my data-set is:

```
MALL_DESC,

OUTLET_NAME,

and

ITEMNAME


the datatable in my data set are also the name of columns
in the table in our database.

they are two tables that i joined together.

table1: M_OUTLET

table2: T_SALES_DETAIL
```

when i run my program
my crystal report gives me output like this:

```
MALL_DESC            OUTLET               ITEMNAME

SM LIPA            LIPA CAFE              BLUE CUPCAKE

SM LIPA            LIPA CART              PINK CUPCAKE

SM BACOLOD         BACOLOD CAFE           BLUE CUPCAKE

SM BACOLOD           BACOLOD CART           PINK CUPCAKE
```

but the output i want is this:

```
MALL_DESC            OUTLET         BLUE CUPCAKE           PINKCUPCAKE 

SM LIPA            LIPA CAFE               5                    12

SM LIPA            LIPA CART              23                     7

SM BACOLOD         BACOLOD CAFE            4                     8 

SM BACOLOD           BACOLOD CART           19                     22
```

help me please
and thank you so much.

fionakyla

Comment: where do the numbers come from?

Comment: it came from the total quantity sold of the items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to adjust your dataset some. If the two item names are static, you can have Mall, Outlet, Quantity_blue, Quantity_pink.

In your crystal report, you'll have two groupings stacked directly on top of each other, Mall and Outlet, then all your fields listed under that second grouping.

```
"MALL"   "OUTLET"     "BLUE"   "PINK"    <-labels
----Group by Mall----
----Group by Outlet----
[Mall]    [outlet]    [blue]   [pink]    <- fields from the dataset
```

^hope that makes sense...

Comment: Glad to help out! Welcome to SO.